# Event loop is closed, error after stopping the bot discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

[Intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv0Cw.png)
There is my code, idk why but my commands didn't run, events yes, but commands not. In video on youtube is everything ok. In discord developer portal intents are enabled. So I don't know where is the problem, bot do not react to the commands and when I stopping him I'm getting an error which you can see below.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = "token"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("\n\tOnline")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return


@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    await before.channel.send(
        f'{before.author.mention} edit a message. \n'
        f'Before: {before.content}\n'
        f'After: {after.content}\n'
    )


@client.command()
async def embed(ctx):
    em = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="This is a description", color=0x20B2AA)
    em.set_footer(text='This is a footer.')
    em.set_image(url='')
    # em.set_thumbnail(url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/823480191493210113/886011319688527892/Screenshot_808.png')
    # em.set_author(name='Author Name', icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/823480191493210113/886011319688527892/Screenshot_808.png')
    em.add_field(name='Field Name', value='Field Value', inline=False)
    em.add_field(name='Field Name', value='Field Value', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name='Field Name', value='Field Value', inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)


@client.command()
async def answer(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hi !")

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Traceback

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000021FDF4A3040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\wital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\wital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\wital\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands are not working probably due to `on_message`. Try putting `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of `on_message` and see if that fixes it. This is mentioned [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) in the FAQ section of `discord.py` documentation. And about the error, I am assuming you are stopping the script by pressing `Ctrl+C`. If that is the case, the error shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I didn't understand why my code do not ran.

Comment: And about error, I'm stopping code via button in PyCharm, so idk why is the error.